# NodeJs in Typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, webstorm

I would like to use this way when I'm writing app.ts file.
There are some issues concerning .d.ts imports, I don't get full api exposed of `express`. The issue is that I don't get full autocompletion in Webstorm2016 (haven't tried it vscode - not relevant for me for now).

```
///<reference path="../../typings/main.d.ts"/>
import * as express from 'express';
import * as logger  from 'morgan';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import {join} from 'path';

/* local imports*/
import * as env from '../../tools/tasks';


class Startup {
    private _app: express.Express;
    private _port: number;

    constructor() {
        this._app  = express();
        this._port = env.settings.PORT;

        this.initialize();
        this.setupViews();
        this.listener();
    }

    private initialize() : void {
        // this._app.[use] => not recognized
        this._app.use(logger('dev')); 
        this._app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));
        this._app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this._app.use('/', this.router());
    }

    private setupViews() : void {
        // this._app.[engine] => not recognized
        // this._app.[set]    => not recognized
        this._app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
        this._app.set("views", join(__dirname, "views"));
        this._app.set("view engine", "html");
    }

    private router(): express.Router {
        /* routes */
        let index: express.Router = this._app.get('/', (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
            response.render('index', { title: 'This is express initial' });
        });
        return index;
    }

    private listener() : void {
        let server: any =  this._app.listen(this._port, () => {
            var listeningPort: number = server.address().port;
            console.log('The server is listening on port: ' + listeningPort);
        });
    }
}

declare var app = new Startup();
```

This is my compilation error list:

```
src/server/app.ts(5,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.
src/server/app.ts(8,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../tools/tasks'.
src/server/app.ts(25,13): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(26,13): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(26,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
src/server/app.ts(27,13): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(28,13): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(32,13): error TS2339: Property 'engine' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(32,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
src/server/app.ts(33,13): error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(33,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
src/server/app.ts(34,13): error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(39,41): error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(40,13): error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'Response'.
src/server/app.ts(46,32): error TS2339: Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Express'.
src/server/app.ts(54,17): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

typings.json:

```
        {
          "ambientDependencies": {
             "body-parser": "registry:dt/body-    parser#0.0.0+20160317120654",
 "express":"github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
            "morgan": "registry:dt/morgan#1.2.2+20160317120654",
            "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160319033040",
            "systemjs": "registry:dt/systemjs#0.18.4+20160316155526"
      }
    }
```

Actually have found an answer for that issue. For some reason `typings` stripping the two definitions of:

```
 - express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts"
 - serve-static.d.ts
```

if you install both of them it's starting showing autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

I see no typings for the packages in the code you've pasted.

The most reliable way to solve this issue is to use [TypeScript Definition Manager](https://github.com/typings/typings) to install typings you need.

You also have to provide type references. If you're going to use TypeScript Definition Manger it will look like:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/main.d.ts" />
```

Comment: I'm using typings and I do have a `///<reference path="../../typings/main.d.ts"/>` and still no results.

Comment: I see by the error log that there's no references in the file you pasted.

Comment: Sorry mate but I've did it I will resubmit the error log.

Comment: Ok. There's "Cannot find module 'path'" that means no node.d.ts is installed. Could you provide typings.json for more details?

Comment: I've added the file.

Comment: Strange that a local file not found '../../tools/tasks'. Maybe you've got invalid compiler options, should be "target": "es5", "module": "commonjs". Another way to check correctness is to install Atom with atom-typescript and check it works there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107612/discussion-between-iamstalker-and-maxfx).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing type definitions for express, serve-static, express-serve-static-core, mime as well.

```
typings install dt~node --global --save
typings install dt~express dt~serve-static dt~express-serve-static-core dt~mime --global --save
```

Theses will help auto completion.

Comment: Typings is now depricated. Use `npm i --save @types/express` or `yarn add @types/express`.